# Cannot get Android Studio to connect to a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio

I cannot get my Android app (basic just tutorial style app) to connect to my MySQL database.  I can get a basic IntelliJ IDEA program with essentially the same code to connect and display a list of names, but my android app just throws `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`.

When I look at the server logs in MySQL Workbench, the result is `Access denied for user '(myname)'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

The weird thing is that when I check the log after I connect using my java program on IntelliJ, the logs show the same thing, several reconnect attempts, then `Aborted connection 458 to db: 'mydb' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)`, then the same `Access denied...` message, but the names DO print out to the terminal in the IntelliJ app.

I created a user of my username on my Mac account I am using and nothing really matters. Same message. Any idea where I should go?

Here is the Android Studio Code:

```
package com.addydevelopments.sqlllllll;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text, errorText;
    Button show;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        errorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Task().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String records="", error="";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&serverTimezone=GMT";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "student";


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "SELECT * from mydb.fruit";
                ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);

                while(rs.next()){
                    records += rs.getString("name") + "/n";

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                error = e.toString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            text.setText(records);

            if(error != ""){
                errorText.setText(error);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the IntelliJ IDEA version:

```
package com.addydevelopments.Dahls;

import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=GMT";

        String user = "root";
        String password = "student";
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement myState = myConn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * from mydb.fruit";
            ResultSet rs = myState.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 1):

Your code connects to a local sql server. There is not one running on your Android phone whilst I assume there is one running on your computer. You can use httpurlconnection to talk to your external web server and use php/sql on the server side. Just a note if the server doesn’t have a valid ssl certificate it may not work.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection

Comment: Thanks for your help I got that all figured out a while ago just never got back to you